# ¿Como guardar valor de datepicker que se encuentra en un edittext en sqlite android studio?

Tags: android-studio, android-sqlite, datepicker

No puedo guardar el valor del datepicker que se muestra en el edittext en sqlite, me arroja al guardar el siguiente error:

> E/SQLiteLog: (1) table paciente has no column named fechaNacimiento
> E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting nombre=g fechaNacimiento=7/1/2021 dni=3
> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table paciente has no column named fechaNacimiento (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: INSERT INTO paciente(nombre,fechaNacimiento,dni) VALUES (?,?,?)
> at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
> at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:986)
> at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:593)
> at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:590)
> at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.(SQLiteProgram.java:61)
> at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.(SQLiteStatement.java:33)
> at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1597)
> at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1468)
> at com.example.nihcalculadoramdica.registro.registrarPacientes(registro.java:87)
> at com.example.nihcalculadoramdica.registro.onClick(registro.java:75)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:409)
> at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7185)
> at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:992)
> at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7162)
> at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:819)
> at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27691)
> at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7560)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)

Hasta el momento de agregar fecha guardaba bien el nombre y el dni, la tabla es la siguiente:

```
public class Utilidades {

    //Constantes campos tabla pacientes
    public static final String TABLA_PACIENTE="paciente";
    public static final String CAMPO_ID="id";
    public static final String CAMPO_DNI="dni";
    public static final String CAMPO_NOMBRE="nombre";
    public static final String CAMPO_FECHA_NACIMIENTO="fechaNacimiento";


    public final static String CREAR_TABLA_PACIENTE="CREATE TABLE "+TABLA_PACIENTE+" ("+CAMPO_ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+CAMPO_DNI+" TEXT, "+CAMPO_NOMBRE+" TEXT, "+CAMPO_FECHA_NACIMIENTO+" TEXT)";
```

Continuación de código:

```
public class ConexionSQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {



    public ConexionSQLiteHelper(@Nullable Context context, @Nullable String name, @Nullable SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        super(context, name, factory, version);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(Utilidades.CREAR_TABLA_PACIENTE);
        db.execSQL(Utilidades.CREAR_TABLA_RESULTADO);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int versionAntigua, int versionNueva) {

        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+Utilidades.TABLA_PACIENTE);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+Utilidades.TABLA_RESULTADO);
        onCreate(db);
    }
}
```

Entidad paciente:

```
public class Paciente {

    private Integer id;
    private String dni;
    private String nombre;
    private String resultado;
    private String nivel;
    private String fecha;
    private String fechaNacimiento;

    public Paciente() {
        this.id = id;
        this.dni = dni;
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.resultado = resultado;
        this.nivel = nivel;
        this.fecha = fecha;
        this.fechaNacimiento = fechaNacimiento;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getDni() {
        return dni;
    }

    public void setDni(String dni) {
        this.dni = dni;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public String getResultado() { return resultado; }

    public void setResultado(String resultado) { this.resultado = resultado; }

    public String getNivel() { return nivel; }

    public void setNivel(String nivel) { this.nivel = nivel; }

    public String getFecha() {
        return fecha;
    }

    public void setFecha(String fecha) {
        this.fecha = fecha;
    }

    public String getFechaNacimiento() {
        return fechaNacimiento;
    }

    public void setFechaNacimiento(String fechaNacimiento) { this.fechaNacimiento = fechaNacimiento; }
}
```

Clase donde esta el datepicker y función registrar para guardar en sqlite:

```
public class registro extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText campoDni, campoNombre, campoFecha;
    Intent i;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.registro);

        campoDni = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.dniPaciente);
        campoNombre = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.nombrePaciente);
        campoFecha =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.fechaNacimiento);
        campoFecha.setFocusable(false);
        campoFecha.setKeyListener(null);


        i= new Intent(registro.this, MainActivity.class);

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        final int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        final int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        final int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);


        campoFecha.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(registro.this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
                    month = month+1;
                    String date = day+"/"+month+"/"+year;
                    campoFecha.setText(date);
                    }
                },year,month,day);

                datePickerDialog.show();
            }
        });

    }


    public void onClick (View view){

        registrarPacientes();
    }

    private void registrarPacientes() {
        ConexionSQLiteHelper conn = new ConexionSQLiteHelper(this, "bd_pacientes",null,1);

        SQLiteDatabase db =conn.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(Utilidades.CAMPO_DNI,campoDni.getText().toString());
        values.put(Utilidades.CAMPO_NOMBRE,campoNombre.getText().toString());
        values.put(Utilidades.CAMPO_FECHA_NACIMIENTO,campoFecha.getText().toString());

        Long idResultante =db.insert(TABLA_PACIENTE,Utilidades.CAMPO_ID,values);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Id Registro: "+ idResultante + " ¡Paciente cargado correctamente!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        db.close();
    }

    public void registroAinicio(View view){
        startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

Desde ya gracias y espero que puedan guiarme con esto, un saludo.

> **PD:** Ya había desinstalado la app y vuelto a instalar luego de agregar una nueva columna a la tabla y daba el mismo problema.

Comment: Hola, por el tipo de error que se lee, al parecer a la tabla no se le está creando el campo fechaNacimiento, de haber actualizado tu estructura en alguna parte de tu código debes tener un lugar en donde estés enviando el numero de versión de la tabla. Para que se ejecute el `onUpgrade` tienes que cambiar el numero de versión y así actualizar la estructura, En la documentación tienen comentado  _If you change the database schema, you must increment the database version._ [enlace]https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/sqlite#DbHelper

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu respuesta, efectivamente, cambie las lineas: conn = new ConexionSQLiteHelper(getApplicationContext(),"bd_pacientes",null,1); por conn = new ConexionSQLiteHelper(getApplicationContext(),"bd_pacientes",null,2); y listo, ya guardaba bien la fecha y creaba la columna, hice consutas y si, guarda y trae bien la info, muchas gracias, me salvaste de esto.

Comment: @DiegoCardoso  no necesitas cambiar la versión de la base de datos, únicamente elimina caché o elimina la app y vuelve a subirla,

Answer (score 0):

El problema que tienes esta relacionado a una tabla en tu base de datos, se indica en el LogCat:

> SQLiteException: table paciente has no column named fechaNacimiento
> (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: INSERT INTO
> paciente(nombre,fechaNacimiento,dni) VALUES (?,?,?)

Tu tabla `paciente` no contiene una columna llamada `fechaNacimiento`, al revisar la creación de tu tabla , el script que crea la tabla incorrecto:

```
public class Utilidades {

    //Constantes campos tabla pacientes
    public static final String TABLA_PACIENTE="paciente";
    public static final String CAMPO_ID="id";
    public static final String CAMPO_DNI="dni";
    public static final String CAMPO_NOMBRE="nombre";
    public static final String CAMPO_FECHA_NACIMIENTO="fechaNacimiento";


    public final static String CREAR_TABLA_PACIENTE="CREATE TABLE "+TABLA_PACIENTE+" ("+CAMPO_ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+CAMPO_DNI+" TEXT, "+CAMPO_NOMBRE+" TEXT, "+CAMPO_FECHA_NACIMIENTO+" TEXT)";
```

Por lo tanto el problema debe ser que creaste una estructura incorrecta, te sugiero eliminar el caché de tu aplicación o eliminar la aplicación y volver a subirla.